# My app keep stopping after i added data base code - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I don't know what is the problem of my database, my app keep stopping after i added the data base code.
Please can you help with to fix that.
I have tried many times to figure it out but still not getting anywhere.

This is my data base code :
public class databaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

```
// Country table name
private static final String TABLE_NAME= "contacts";

// Country Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String NAME = "Name";
private static final String PHONENO = "PhoneNo";

public databaseOpenHelper(Context context){
    super(context,"Login.db",null,1);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase myDB) {
    myDB.execSQL("create Table users(username Text primary key,password Text)");

    // create the table for the first time
    String CREATE_COUNTRY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + NAME + " TEXT,"
            + PHONENO + " TEXT" + ")";
    myDB.execSQL(CREATE_COUNTRY_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase myDB, int i, int i1) {
    myDB.execSQL("drop Table if exists users");
}

public Boolean isertData(String username,String password){
    SQLiteDatabase myDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("username",username);
    contentValues.put("password",password);
    long result = myDB.insert("users",null,contentValues);

    if(result == -1){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}


public Boolean checkusername(String username){
    SQLiteDatabase myDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = myDB.rawQuery("select * from users where username = ?",new String[] {username});
    if (cursor.getCount()>0){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

public Boolean checkusernamePassword(String username,String password){
    SQLiteDatabase myDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = myDB.rawQuery("select * from users where username = ? and password = ?",new String[] {username,password});
    if (cursor.getCount()>0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}



// method to add the contact
public void addcontact(ContactModel contact){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues c=new ContentValues();
    c.put(NAME,contact.getName());
    c.put(PHONENO,contact.getPhoneNo());
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,c);
    db.close();
}

// method to retrieve all the contacts in List
public List<ContactModel> getAllContacts(){
    List<ContactModel> list=new ArrayList<>();
    String query="SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery(query,null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            list.add(new ContactModel(c.getInt(0),c.getString(1),c.getString(2)));

        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return list;
}

// get the count of data, this will allow user
// to not add more that five contacts in database
public int count(){
    int count=0;
    String query="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery(query,null);
    if(c.getCount()>0){
        c.moveToFirst();
        count=c.getInt(0);
    }
    c.close();
    return count;
}
// Deleting single country
public void deleteContact(ContactModel contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    int i=db.delete(TABLE_NAME,KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getId()) });

    db.close();
}
```

}

And this is my logcat :
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.localisation, PID: 11700
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.localisation/com.example.localisation.phone}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: contacts (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM contacts
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3635)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: contacts (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM contacts
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1047)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:654)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:62)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1546)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1485)
at com.example.localisation.databaseOpenHelper.getAllContacts(databaseOpenHelper.java:108)
at com.example.localisation.phone.onCreate(phone.java:81)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8051)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8031)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3608)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)

Comment: Did you forget to create the table `contacts`?

Comment: I created but i have two tables i don't know is the code that i writed is correct. Can you shake it please

Comment: No, you did not create `contacts`. The error message is: "no such table: contacts (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM contacts at". Uninstall the app from the device and rerun.

Comment: Then can you tell me where i should create the table

Answer (score 0):

The failure is saying that there is not a table called **contacts** as per

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: contacts (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM contacts
```

Running your code and then using the errant **getAllContacts** method, as indicated in the log by:-

```
at com.example.localisation.databaseOpenHelper.getAllContacts(databaseOpenHelper.java:108)
```

Works.

As such it is highly likely that you have added the **contacts** cable **after previously running the App** and that this has created the database. The database persists and thus will still exist from on run to the other. As such the **`onCreate`** method will not be called, as it is only called once when the database is created.

The easy fix is to uninstall the App and rerun. **However**, this will delete any existing data.

If you need to keep any data then you should **a)** increase the version number and then **b)** add code to the **onUpgrade** method to create the new table (same code).

For example:-

**a)**

```
public databaseOpenHelper(Context context){
   super(context,"Login.db",null,2 /*<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED */);
}
```

**b)**

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase myDB, int i, int i1) {
   //myDB.execSQL("drop Table if exists users");
   if (i1 == 2) {
      String CREATE_COUNTRY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
             + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + NAME + " TEXT,"
             + PHONENO + " TEXT" + ")";
      myDB.execSQL(CREATE_COUNTRY_TABLE);

   }
}
```

You can the see that the contacts table has been created by using App Inspection e.g.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

according to the error code you uploaded i noticed this `SELECT * FROM contacts` which means that you don't have table named contacts in you sqlite database so i recommend you, for testing you should use sqlite browser  to create database and add data to it and then use it in your android studio project. if you get any problem fearther don't hesitate to ask it in comments thanks.